# Running multiple queries in model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have this code in model in codeigniter:

```
<?php
Class Mymodel Extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function search($textinput)
    {
        $street = "select street from dataSearch;";
        $stripNameWOSpace = "select stripNameWOSpace FROM dataSearch;";
        $vowels = array('a','e','i','o','u',';','/','-', ' ');
        $string = strtolower($textinput);
        $strippedVowels = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace($vowels, '', $string));
            $this->db->query("select dataSearch.id,
                dataSearch.name,
                dataSearch.street,
                dataSearch.city,
                dataSearch.lat,
                dataSearch.lng,
                category.asiatype from dataSearch join category on dataSearch.cat = category.id
                where dataSearch.street like '%".$textinput."%'");
            $this->db->query("select dataSearch.id,
                dataSearch.name,
                dataSearch.street,
                dataSearch.city,
                dataSearch.lat,
                dataSearch.lng,
                category.asiatype from dataSearch join category on dataSearch.cat = category.id
                where dataSearch.stripNameWOSpace like '%".$strippedVowels."%'");
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $query->result();

    }
}
?>
```

I just want to execute multiple queries. You notice in where statement the two have different condition. I just want to get the result for the two queries.
I try the switch statement to execute both queries and it is not working. Help me.

Comment: what  is your condition for this code?

Comment: How can I add condition or statement in this code?Can you help me?I'm new in codeigniter. My condition would be, if both queries is true both will get the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the query to a variable to do your things with each query.

Like this:

```
Class Mymodel Extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function search($textinput) {
        $query1 = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
        $query2 = $this->db->query("YOUR SECOND QUERY");

        $result1 = $query1->result();
        $result2 = $query2->result();

        return array_merge($result1, $result2); // If you want to merge both results
    }
}
```

In your controller:

```
$this->load->model('Mymodel');
$searchresult = $this->Mymodel->search($textinput);
```

For more information, you should read [CodeIgniter User Guide - Model](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html)

Comment: But how can I call the variables in controller.

Comment: I have updated my answer, check it out. And don't forget to take a look at the link.

Comment: How about if I want to get the result both queries eventhough it will get duplicate entry?

Comment: Try replace `return array_merge($result1, $result2);` with `return $result1 + $result2;`

Comment: how to get my qry1 value.?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [store_name] => Shambhavi [fullname] => Suhani K ) [1] => Array ( [mobile_no] => 123456789 [store_name] => Cvv13 [business_address] => [GST_No] => 22334455667788 [reg_address] => hhjhjhjjh ) )

Answer (score 1):

I know...old, was looking for something else when I saw something that could be done better. the two select statements are identical except for the where statement. you can use "OR" to combine the two WHERE statements. use "DISTINCT" to avoid duplicate entries. "UNION" should be used if you really want duplicate entries.