# Codeigniter: extra parameters being inserted into MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a model with several functions, one of which is supposed to delete some records from several tables that match a specified tag number. However, when I output the MySQL statement to the error log, I see that it's adding some extra parameters, which appears to be taken from another function in the model. It's quite bizarre, and I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on.

Here's the function:

```
function deleteEquipment() {
    $tag = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->db->where('tag', $tag);
    $this->db->delete('equipment');
    error_log('mysql: '.$this->db->last_query());
    $this->db->where('tag', $tag);
    $this->db->delete('process_record');
    $this->db->where('tag', $tag);
    $this->db->delete('hold');
    $this->db->where('tag', $tag);
    $this->db->delete('dpo');
    error_log('mysql: '.$this->db->last_query());
    return;
}
```

Here is the error log:

```
WHERE (archived<>'yes' AND (on_lot<>'yes' OR photographs_uploaded<>'yes') AND sold<>'yes') OR (archived<>'yes' AND sold='yes' AND (final_inspection<>'yes' OR jdlink2_registered<>'yes'))
AND `tag` =  '40'
[24-Jun-2015 16:10:21 Europe/Berlin] mysql: DELETE FROM `process_record`
WHERE `tag` =  '40'
[24-Jun-2015 16:10:21 Europe/Berlin] mysql: DELETE FROM `hold`
WHERE `tag` =  '40'
[24-Jun-2015 16:10:21 Europe/Berlin] mysql: DELETE FROM `dpo`
WHERE `tag` =  '40'
```

So, the last three statements look fine, but the first has all of these extra parameters inserted into the statement. The only other place I see these parameters are in a couple of functions in the same model that relate to pagination, e.g.:

```
function getRowCount() {
        // to do: edit this
        $q = $this->db->get('equipment');
        $where = "(archived<>'yes' AND (on_lot<>'yes' OR photographs_uploaded<>'yes') AND sold<>'yes') OR (archived<>'yes' AND sold='yes' AND (final_inspection<>'yes' OR jdlink2_registered<>'yes'))"; 
        $this->db->where($where);
        $rowcount = $q->num_rows();
        return $rowcount;       
    }
```

I don't have a clue why the parameters from a completely separate function are showing up in the first MySQL statement. Note: There is another function in the same model where the same thing is happening: A few updates to three separate tables where the row matches a tag number. The equipment table query pulls in this weird stuff, but the other queries look fine.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: You need to create different instances for each query. currently it is being combined in each other. 
For example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869603/running-multiple-queries-in-model-in-codeigniter#21869647

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Record is caching the `WHERE` in `getRowCount` because you are calling the methods out of order.

Your application calls `deleteEquipment` while the `WHERE` from `getRowCount` is still in the Active Record cache.

```
function getRowCount() {
        // move line below
        // $q = $this->db->get('equipment');
        $where = "(archived<>'yes' AND (on_lot<>'yes' OR photographs_uploaded<>'yes') AND sold<>'yes') OR (archived<>'yes' AND sold='yes' AND (final_inspection<>'yes' OR jdlink2_registered<>'yes'))"; 
        $this->db->where($where);

        // Active record will now clear the WHERE cache after executing get
        $q = $this->db->get('equipment');
        $rowcount = $q->num_rows();
        return $rowcount;       
    }
```

Comment: That worked! For some reason I assumed that the functions were relatively isolated from one another. Thanks so much for the solution and clarification.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `$this->db->get()`, you *run* the query.  So, in your `getRowCount()` function, you run `SELECT * FROM equipment`, then you set a where clause.

That where clause is set, but not used until the *next* query, which is in the `deleteEquipment()` function.

You need to do this:

```
function getRowCount() {
    $where = "(archived<>'yes' AND (on_lot<>'yes' OR photographs_uploaded<>'yes') AND sold<>'yes') OR (archived<>'yes' AND sold='yes' AND (final_inspection<>'yes' OR jdlink2_registered<>'yes'))"; 
    $this->db->where($where);

    $q = $this->db->get('equipment');
    $rowcount = $q->num_rows();
    return $rowcount;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function getRowCount(), $this->db->get must come last. It should be like this:

```
function getRowCount() {
        // to do: edit this            
        $where = "(archived<>'yes' AND (on_lot<>'yes' OR photographs_uploaded<>'yes') AND sold<>'yes') OR (archived<>'yes' AND sold='yes' AND (final_inspection<>'yes' OR jdlink2_registered<>'yes'))"; 
        $this->db->where($where);
        $q = $this->db->get('equipment');
        $rowcount = $q->num_rows();
        return $rowcount;       
    }
```

In your code, because $this->db->where() is not followed by $this->db->get() immediately, causing the condition still be kept for next query.