# how to fire two query in a function with two different result

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session

How to fire two query in a function with two different result :

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$role = $_SESSION['user_role'];

$this->db->select("date_of_birth");
$this->db->from("student_basic_details");
$this->db->join('users', 'student_basic_details.student_id=users.user_id');
$this->db->where('users.role', $role);
$this->db->where('student_id', $id);
$student_birthday = $this->db->get()->row_array();

$this->db->select('date_of_birth');
$this->db->from('staff_basic_details');
$this->db->join('users', 'staff_basic_details.id=users.user_id');
$this->db->where('users.role', $role);
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$staff_birthday = $this->db->get()->row_array();

print_r($student_birthday);
exit();
```

But both the queriers $student_birthday and $staff_birthday retured the same result.

Comment: And what do you expect?

Comment: i want different birthdate from $student_birthday and $staff_birthday

Comment: `print_r($this->db->queries);` take a look @ your sql statements and you should be able to find your problem...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running multiple queries in model in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869603/running-multiple-queries-in-model-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Show example table contents & results & expected results for each query.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution for you problem :

```
$qry1 = $this->db->query("QUERY1");
$qry2 = $this->db->query("QUERY2");

$query = $this->db->query(' (".$qry1.") UNION ALL (".$qry2.") ');

return $query->result();
```

I Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS IN MODEL:

```
$qry1 = $this->db->query("QUERY1");
$qry2 = $this->db->query("QUERY2");

$res1 = $qry1->result();
$res2 = $qry2->result();
```